# jquery not updating handlebars partial view correctly (express, node.js)

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

**Updated to show how to get this to work**. The answer I accepted below didn't really show much code, everything ended up in the comments. So for simplicity, I've shown the correct code here (my original code had 3 errors).

I'm using Node.JS with Express and Handlebars. I was having trouble just updating a particular div as well as sending data. This is what worked.

Inside my view directory I have: index.handlebars, view1.handlebars, temp.handlebars.

Inside view1.handlebars, I have a `button`:

```
<button type="button"  id="btn-here" data-id="{{data.uniqueId}}"><a href="../update_this">Update This</a></button>
```

and a `div`:

```
<div id="sectional">
    {{> partial}}
</div>
```

And when someone clicks the `button`, I want to update the sectional `div`. So I use jquery like so:

```
$('#btn-here').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id_num = $(this).data('id'); //id_num is correct

    $.get("/temp/" + id_num, function(res) {
       var updated_html = res;
       $('#sectional').html(updated_html);
   });
});
```

I allow the jquery to find the temp.handlebars file via:

```
router.get('/temp/:id', view1.showstuff);
```

And inside the view1.showstuff function:

```
showstuff: function(req, res) {
            res.locals.model = model;
            res.render('temp/' + id, {layout: false});
        };
```

This now sends along the view data and updates only the view specified in the jquery call.

Thanks for help to the user below!

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://yoursite.com/temp.html` in your browser? Do you just get the contents of `temp.html` or the whole `index.html` contents?

Comment: Well, since I'm using Node.JS with express (& handlebars) I get the error message that the browser can't "GET /temp.html". I don't have it as a route in my routes.js file.

Comment: What does the Network tab of the Chrome devtools say gets returned when you request `temp.html`? Is `temp.html` an actual file you expect to be getting? If so, you will need your routes configured to allow you to fetch it via some URL.

Comment: Well, I print to console the contents of the file it "gets" and it is the index page, not my temp.html page. I'm really confused how it gets this.

Comment: It will be something to do with how your routes are configured. I recommend you post: 1) the basic file structure of your project, including where `temp.html` is. 2) the route configuration code. 3) the URL of the page where you are trying to click the `#btn-here` button.

Comment: ` {{> partial this}}` , is `this` needed  for you?

Comment: At the moment, I guess the `this` isn't needed.

Comment: @GregL: I have checked and see that my routes call seems to do nothing (I tried putting in nonesense, leaving it blank, etc., and it doesn't have any effect). The jquery call over-rides the call to the routes with the `event.preventDefault()`. So everything that happens occurs in the jquery call.

Comment: @GregL: I updated my code description to include more details. I'm hoping the mistake is obvious.

Comment: Yep, the problem might be with how I'm doing the `/` in the html, jquery vs. routes calls... All kinds of strange things happen when I add/remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need a router handler as follows

```
app.get('/temp.html', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('temp', {layout: false});
});
```

Or place your temp.html in public folder but then you can't use {{> partials}} as its not processed by view engine

Comment: You mean get rid of the jquery call altogether and just use the render? But then how does it know to just update the sectional div?

Comment: No, the jQuery is ok. But for the jquery $.get("temp.html"... to work you need app.get('/temp.html'... handler on the server or if the temp.html is static html file you can place it in public folder

Comment: Ok, just to get things working, I originally had temp.html inside the public folder. But I want to do things the right way, so I put the file back into the views directory and then added this res.render call. I am getting the same behavior. The index page appears in my #sectional div! I print the output of the "res" from the jquery call and it is definitely loading index.handlebars, not my temp.handlebars file.

Comment: if the temp.html is static html then putting it in public folder is the right way

Comment: It's not actually going to be static in the end. I just did that because I was trying to debug my problem. I've modified my description of the code to show the current structure. Same problem.

Comment: Now you have :id in your router.get... so in $.get....  You need to change the path to '/temp/<some-id-here>' or change server route to router.get('/temp', view1.sh......

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I had to play with `/` to get things to display, but if I don't try to send along the id or model (which contains the data for the view) then things are now displaying! I put the two calls that I tried to get the id and model through and they generate different error messages (see the edits under showstuff).

Comment: You can only have one res.render..., To pass data to view you need to attach it like  res.locals.model = model;  I would recommend you to read some tutorials about express or watch some videos on YouTube. Good bye :)

Comment: Of course, I was only showing the 3 different calls I tried. Ok, I will search for tutorials if this is actually something obvious. Thx for the help. Accepting your answer since it got me the closest there.